# Extract text from Google Sheets using REGEXExtract

Tags: regex, google-sheets, re2

I'm trying to extract the company name from these text strings in Google Sheets. However, I can't get my head wrapped around regular expressions and regexextract.

Strings:

```
S-1 - Wealthbridge Acquisition Ltd (0001753673) (Filer)
S-1/A - KinerjaPay Corp. (0001494162) (Filer)
S-1 - CYTY CAPITAL SOLUTIONS INC (0001762609) (Filer)
S-1/A - NORTHWEST OIL & GAS TRADING COMPANY, INC. (0001762533) (Filer)
```

Intended result:

```
Wealthbridge Acquisition Ltd
KinerjaPay Corp.
CYTY CAPITAL SOLUTIONS INC
NORTHWEST OIL & GAS TRADING COMPANY, INC.
```

I've tried reading the Google Sheets documentation on REGEXExtract and many other sources, but none of it makes sense. I would turn to YouTube but unfortunately that's blocked at work. Thanks in advance community!

I tried this: =REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\s(.*)(")
which is getting closer but I still have no clue what I'm doing.

EDIT: Holy macaroni I figured it out! I'm not sure how it works, but it works.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\s(\w.*)\(0")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all follows that pattern ( dash name of company (number) ) the following works using REGEXEXTRACT.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2; "-\s([^\(]+)")
```

My goal was to match the dash, after the space (\s) and after that GROUP everything one or more times until i found a parenthesis on the string.

Also, i used [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/19hFE6/2) to verify the pattern and made it work on google sheet.

Comment: I saw you edited your post, want to clarify your code will work except if the first number on the parenthesis isn't zero so, be carefull with that.